# Problems extracting data using pandas from a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract the dates over a specified period of time from a csv file to a pandas dataframe that I can then use to trend data and plot using matplotlib. When run the program repeats the printed data, and I have tried using indexing, and the function def filter_data_by_date(df, start_date, end_date): show the correct indexes but the program duplicates the entries and also does not show the full dates.

[Error message and program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VpDa.png)

The csv file has the following data:
[CSV file "task4anew1.csv"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nqiv.png)

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def is_valid_date(date_text):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(date_text, '%d/%m/%Y')
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def input_date():
    while True:
        start_date_input = input("Enter start date (dd/mm/yyyy): ")
        if is_valid_date(start_date_input):
            start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date_input, '%d/%m/%Y')
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid date format. Please enter date in dd/mm/yyyy format.")

    while True:
        end_date_input = input("Enter end date (dd/mm/yyyy): ")
        if is_valid_date(end_date_input):
            end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date_input, '%d/%m/%Y')
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid date format. Please enter date in dd/mm/yyyy format.")

    return start_date, end_date

def read_csv_data():
    filename = 'task4anew1.csv'  
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    return df


def filter_data_by_date(df, start_date, end_date):
    date_columns = df.columns[2:]
    date_columns = pd.to_datetime(date_columns, format='%d/%m/%Y')
    start_index = date_columns.get_loc(start_date)
    end_index = date_columns.get_loc(end_date)
    print(start_index)
    print(end_index)

    filtered_columns = ['Restaurant', 'Food'] + list(df.columns[start_index:end_index+1])
    filtered_df = df[filtered_columns]
    print (filtered_df)
    return filtered_df



def main_menu():
    flag = True

    while flag:
        print("#################################################")
        print("#### Welcome to Fast Food Takeaways ####")
        print("#################################################")
        print("")
        print("########### Please select an option #############")
        print("### 1. Nandos")
        print("### 2. KFC")
        print("### 3. Dominoes")
        choice = input('Enter your number selection here: ')

        try:
            int(choice)
        except:
            print("Sorry, you did not enter a valid option")
            flag = True
        else:
            print('Choice accepted!')
            flag = False

    return choice

def convert_menu_choice(choice):
    if choice == "1":
        conv_choice = "Nandos"
        return conv_choice
    elif choice == "2":
        conv_choice = "KFC"
        return conv_choice
    elif choice == "3":
        conv_choice = "Dominoes"
        return conv_choice

    print(conv_choice)

# Start of the program
main_menu_choice = main_menu()
fastfood = convert_menu_choice(main_menu_choice)

start_date, end_date = input_date()


df = read_csv_data()
filtered_df = filter_data_by_date(df, start_date, end_date)
print(filtered_df)
```

I have tried using slicing and this does not work. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Please help us helping you and avoid images to share error messages and data.

Answer (score 0):

You overlooked that you take `start_index` and `end_index` from `date_columns`, while you use them to index `df.columns`, where they are too low by 2. Among the numerous ways to fix this are adding 2 to those indexes or using `df.columns[2:][start_index:end_index+1]`. But the code could be made a lot simpler by not using `datetime` values at all for `start_date` and `end_date`, but rather the input date strings directly with `df.columns.get_loc()`.